# FaceTrackingBaciscWPF example - how to make facetrackingviewer scale?

Tags: wpf, xaml, kinect-sdk

I am working with FaceTrackingBaciscWPF example and I wanted to change the layout of MainWindow.xaml, so  that it contains 2 columns - ColorViewer with overlayed skeleton in the first one and some text fields in the second one.

When I introduce rows and columns, the colorimage scales as expected, but I don't know how to make rendered face and skeleton "fit" the color image. *How to make the faceTrackingViewer scale too?*

Below my MainWindow.xaml.

```
    <Window 
        x:Class="FaceTrackingBasics.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FaceTrackingBasics"
        Title="Face Tracking Basics"
        Closed="WindowClosed"
        Height="849.925" Width="1017.761" 
        >

    <Window.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MediumGreyBrush" Color="#ff6e6e6e"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="KinectPurpleBrush" Color="#ff52318f"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="KinectBlueBrush" Color="#ff00BCF2"/>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid Name="layoutGrid" Margin="10,0,-83,10">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <DockPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0 0 0 20">
            <Image DockPanel.Dock="Left" Source="Images\Logo.png" Stretch="Fill" Height="32" Width="81" Margin="0 10 0 5"/>
            <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="0 0 -1 0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Foreground="{StaticResource MediumGreyBrush}" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="18">Face Tracking Basics</TextBlock>
            <Image Grid.Column="1" Source="Images\Status.png" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0 0 0 5"/>
        </DockPanel>
        <Viewbox Grid.Row="1" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Grid Name="MainGrid" Width="707" Height="417">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="500"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Name="ColorImage" Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400" Height="480"/>
                <local:FaceTrackingViewer  Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Width="400" Height="480"  x:Name="faceTrackingViewer"/>
                <Label Content="curHeadZ" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,94,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <Label Content="curNoseZ" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="9,63,-4,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <Label Content="shiftHead" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,37,-1,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <Label Content="shiftNose" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,-6,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <TextBox Name="curHeadZ" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="82,96,-130,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
                <TextBox Name="curNoseZ" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="79,69,-128,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
                <TextBox Name="shiftHeadZ" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="80,41,-130,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
                <TextBox Name="shiftNoseZ"  Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="79,13,-130,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
                <Label Content="pitch" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,125,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <Label Content="roll" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,151,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <Label Content="yaw" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,177,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="pitchValText" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="82,128,-128,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="rollValText" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="82,156,-126,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="yawValText" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="82,180,-124,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
                <Button Content="TakePicture" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="11,226,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="TakePictureButtonColor_Click"/>

            </Grid>
        </Viewbox>
   </Grid>
</Window>
```

Probably it's something obvious that I am missing here, but I am just beginning so please help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove the Width & Height specifiers from the XAML as follows:

```
<local:FaceTrackingViewer Margin="0,0,0,0"
                          Grid.Column="0"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                          VerticalAlignment="Top"
                          x:Name="faceTrackingViewer"/>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the HorizontalAlignment & VerticalAlignment properties to 'Stretch'?

Comment: No, still the same problem.
I have a grid 2x2 and facetrackingviewer scales fine with rows but it somehow doesnt 'see' that it should be only in column 0

Comment: Yes I have, I set them to "Stretch" in both colorimage and facetrackingviewer, no effect